# How threatening is instant human extinction to life on earth?

Tags: post-apocalypse, ecology, extinction

All humans magically drop dead this very instant.

How badly will this affect other lifeforms on the Earth?

Ideas:

- Will nuclear plants leak radiation since there is no one left to man them?
- Will electricity grids catch fire? What about industries? How much of the earth's forest cover is likely to burn as a consequence of this (if such fires are indeed likely)?
- Is the food chain affected for the worse? I'm guessing no but I could be wrong.

Comment: Please see [How to deal with “I have a High Concept, please do my work for me” questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/809) and [Is broad impact of a specific change too broad?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6059/809) on meta.

Comment: There is a TV show "Life after people" which explain pretty well all the aspects of a earth without men (in the series, people disappears, don't explicitly die)

Comment: (1) Nuclear plants will eventually leak radioactive materials. Nothing important will happen as a result. (2) Parts of the electricity grid will catch fire. Nothing important will happen as a result. (3) A tiny small part of the forest cover will burn. (4) There is no such thing as "the" food chain -- there many many food chains. (5) In the absence of humans there is no "better" and no "worse"; best, better, good, bad, worse and worst are meaningless in the absence of an [axiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiology).

Comment: @AlexP Yeah I think only rodents, livestock, and house pets will even notice that we're gone and while it might be individually terminal to many their species will carry on as if we never happened in the first place.

Comment: I wrote a long answer going into details about some of the things that would happen, points 1 to 3 of what @AlexP said. But also about the consequences if global warning reached a point of no return. As well as another doomsday scenario related to offshore oil drilling - basically if the drilling mechanisms failed on every platform (which would happen eventually) enough oil could leak to cover all oceans (the numbers work out) with devastating results. But now it's locked and I can't post it -_-

Comment: @Syzygy Keep the material for the answer, you'll use it some day.

Comment: Livestock will perish. Maggots will proliferate, for a while. That's essentially all.

Comment: Domesticated animals will suffer, a few insects will boom and then die off to manageable populations, mice will be devastated, but on the whole everyone else will get a new lease on life, seas will clean themselves, plantlife will flourish in places it hasn't for centuries etc,. 2 billion human corpses is a LOT of fertiliser and scavenger food, many animal, plant and insect populations will boom.

Comment: Every reactor on the planet goes Fukushima.  Some things near them die, in the big picture it's a tiny blip in the death rate.

Answer (score 5):

Heyo! Wolf here!

Quite frankly, me and me chums don't give a fiddler's fart if you lot go suddenly extinct next week. As a matter of fact, friend, you humans can all just drop dead right now and, well, we won't even shed a tear!

We've heard the news in the wind about our cousins over in Ukraine: they seem to be doing fine for all your race's stupidity in the nuclear department, so I suspect we'll do okay here too!

Your electric grids and industries don't do us any favours now, and the sooner you all drop dead the better. Sure, there may be some local brush fires and so forth, but we're good runners! You won't catch a wolf so easily!

And, ah, the old web o' life! Yeah, no worries there! What with no busy-body ranchers to fly up in the air and kill us with their guns, we'll be feasting like kings!

For a time...

All in all, friend, don't you worry about us one bit! When you lot are snuffed and gone, we'll be right as rain! Sure, there'll be some tough times as prey populations level off, but we're survivors. You know how it is (or you would know if your race hadn't abandoned the Wild Life): the weak die and the strong survive. The survivors will make some new pups and in their time will die as all living things do. Wolves will go on, though, and so will sheep and goats and cows and wildcats and geese and chickens and all the rest. And I daresay all the better for lack of humanity.

Answer (score 3):

I think you choose the wrong adjective. Human extinction won't be threatening for life on Earth. It will be relieving!

Except maybe for those animals forced to rely on humans for nutrition (livestock, chickens in chicken farms, fishes in the bowls downstairs), the rest of nature would surely be relieved of not having this invasive species around.

Unmanned plants would mostly switch off non catastrophically, as they are designed to do so. Local accidents, even severe ones, would be recovered in a human free environment, so the consequences would not be as severe or lasting as one can imagine.